# React Native: iOS Not Building in Xcode

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I'm trying to build my React Native iOS project in Xcode and I'm running into some issues. Every time I try to run I'm getting the errors:

> .../yoga/yoga/YGValue.h: No such file or directory
>
> .../yoga/yoga/YGMarker.h: No such file or directory

I've tried cleaning my project, deleting the derived data and I haven't been able to get it to successfully build.

I'm using React Native version 0.58.0.

I'm also not using Cocoapods.

Comment: hi where you able to solve this? My app also works with react-native run-ios but I can't build using Xcode directly.  I am getting the following error:  fatal error: module map file .....Yogakit.modulemap not found